# Using sed command,replace line ,but not the matching pattern

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I know the replace command

```
sed -i 's/First/Second/' testFile
```

will replace the string "First" with "Second".

But given an input as shown below,

**Infile.txt**

> First "This line is to be deleted."

I want the output to be like this:

**Outfile.txt**

> First "New string to be added."

i.e. "First" should not be replaced.

How do I achieve this desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [specify the address](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-25) for the substitution command:

```
sed -i '/First/s/This line is to be deleted/New string to be added/' testFile
```

Edit: for a variable pattern string:

```
sed -i 's/First \(.*\)/First "New string to be added"/' testFile
```

Comment: The string  "This line is to be deleted" may vary according to my app.

Comment: @Mann So you just want to replace everything after `First`?

Comment: I can not use it as MATCHING PATTERN. For my case,I want to use "First" as PATTERN to be matched

Comment: Only That particular Line.

Comment: @LevLevitsky, you can capture the "First" instead so you don't have to write it twice.

Comment: @doubleDown Yep, but with escaped brackets in won't save any typing :)